# Building poky-tiny for the i.MX6 Ultra Lite Evaluation Kit

Tags: yocto

I'm currently trying to build `poky-tiny` for `imx6ulevk` (using the BSP Yocto Project Environment provided by NXP).

I first followed the Quick Start Guide, tested and everything worked just fine. I then went to the usual `local.conf` file (`/build/conf/local.conf`) and changed the `DISTRO` variable to `poky-tiny`.

In `poky-tiny` distro file (`/sources/poky/meta-yocto/conf/distro/poky-tiny.conf`), I changed the virtual/kernel in the variable `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel` to `linux-imx` and the `PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx` to `3.14.38` which is compatible (I think).

I finally added to the local.conf the variable `IMAGE_FSTYPES` with the value `tar.bz2 ext3 sdcard`.

At this point I tried to build using:

`bitbake core-image-minimal`

this runs without any problems. But it doesn't generate sdcard image or any u-boot images as is expected. The only files generated are:

> core-image-minimal-imx6ulevk-20160517152114.rootfs.cpio.gz
>
> core-image-minimal-imx6ulevk-20160517152114.rootfs.manifest
>
> core-image-minimal-imx6ulevk.cpio.gz
>
> core-image-minimal-imx6ulevk.manifest
>
> modules-imx6ulevk.tgz
>
> zImage
>
> zImage--3.14.38-r0-imx6ul-14x14-evk-20160517152114.dtb
>
> zImage--3.14.38-r0-imx6ul-14x14-evk-csi-20160517152114.dtb
>
> zImage--3.14.38-r0-imx6ulevk-20160517152114.bin
>
> zImage-imx6ul-14x14-evk-csi.dtb
>
> zImage-imx6ul-14x14-evk.dtb
>
> zImage-imx6ulevk.bin

And I got stuck without knowing how to deploy to the `imx6ulevk`. What did I do wrong? Why is yocto not generating the usual sdcard image?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets this what worked for me was the following:

Turns out poky-tiny for imx6ulevk does not create sdcard images normally. So what you need to do, once you build it with a proper kernel, is to manually create a bootable sdcard. This can be done by using gparted cleaning everything in it and adding 2 partitions, then proceed as follow:

1 - First you use gunzip in the file core-image-minimal-imx6ulevk-...-rootfs.cpio.gz.

2 - Call cpio on the generated file: cpio -i -vd < core-image-minimal...-.cpio

3 - You just generated the root file system copy everything into one of the partitions.

4 - the zImage...* files are the generated kernel for the poky-tiny distro. Copy all but the symbolic links to the second partition. You might need to rename the files (I had to) if you're not sure what to rename to, first build regular poky using sdcard image and check out the proper names.

That's pretty much it, you should be able to boot imx6ulevk using the provided files.